# How do I assign roles to people in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot that assigns people roles. But console says it fails whenever I try to test my code saying that member isnt defined. I'm new to J.S. so can you send me some code I can try?

Comment: It's going to very difficult to answer your question properly without your code. Please can you supply a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code?

Comment: Please provide a full sample of your code... And a specific explanation of what is actually failing along with any error messages.

Comment: Yeah sure here it is
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === "N") {
    console.log("Adding role")
    var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'Member');
    member.addrole(role)
     

  }
})

Comment: /home/runner/index.js:50
    var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'Member');
               ^

ReferenceError: member is not defined
    at Client.client.on.msg (/home/runner/index.js:50:16)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that I hope helps you.

Checking if role exists:

```
if(!message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '{Role Name}')){
  message.channel.sendMessage("Role not found.")};
```

Role var (To make next steps easier):

```
let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '{Role Name}')
```

Checking if they already have the role:

```
if (message.member.roles.find(role)) {
     return message.channel.sendMessage('You already have role ' + role.name)
```

Adding the role:

```
message.member.addRole(role);
```

Saying they now have the role (Optional):

```
message.channel.sendMessage("You now have the role " + role.name);
```

Again, I really hope this helped with adding roles to members!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `member` variable defined. You need to define it to use it. You can get the GuildMember instance of whoever sent the message from the `msg` object.
If you look at the documentation for [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), you can see it has a property named `member`.
Try defining `member` from your `msg` object.

```js
const member = msg.member;
```

Comment: does this work in 2021? i think message.member is replaced with message.author

Comment: that seems about right https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message